# Understanding redux sagas and why it's not calling my generator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Can someone explain this to me which im not quite getting from the docs:
I have this:

```
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';

const fetchFromFirebase = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.database().ref('users/').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot) {
        const teamsData = snapshot.val();
        resolve(teamsData)
      }
    });
  });
};

function* fetchTeams(action) {
  console.log('here yes1');
   try {
      const teams = yield call(fetchFromFirebase, action.data.teams);
      yield put({type: "TEAMS_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", teams: teams});
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeEvery("SYNC_FIREBASE_WITH_STORE", fetchTeams);
}

export default rootSaga;
```

Im trying to fetch by firebase and then return. I get that my rootSaga, calls the fetch teams and then I do something when this is retrieved.
But I'm unsure how my actions get used in all this...

currently I can't see the console.log logging anything.

my actions:

```
export const syncFirebaseToStore = (data) => ({
  type: 'SYNC_FIREBASE_WITH_STORE',
  data: data
})

export const teamsFetchSucceeded = (teams) => ({
  type: 'TEAMS_FETCH_SUCCEEDED',
  data: teams
});
```

how can I get it calling the `fetchTeams` function properly.

it is calling the rootSaga just to clarify

and in my store:

```
import rootSaga from '../sagas'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
```

Comment: SYNC_FIREBASE_WITH_STORE !== SYNC_FIREBASE_TO_STORE

Comment: this is true but this is still not picking up my console.log

Comment: I had a similar issue, there was a typo in my code but I didn't see it because somehow chrome's console got cleared. I had to set "Preserve log" option to see it.

Comment: Have you connected the saga to the redux store as a middleware?

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda yes. see edited code

Comment: apologies to one and all, I stupidly wasn't calling my first action. all good now!

Comment: Cool. These thing happen naturally. However, I would advice you to verify the message path before posting a question on stackoverflow